# When adding an rest api client in C# windows form project and .Net 4.8, then NSWAG fails

Tags: c#

When I adding an rest api  client in C# windows form project and .Net 4.8 , recieve following error:

> Checking project for required NuGet packges...
> Downloading service reference from https://tp.tax.gov.ir/req/...
> Adding service reference 2 to the project...
> Generating code to 2.cs...
> ErrorFailed adding service reference(s). Code generation for file NSwag.exe failed.
> Command line: openapi2csclient /input:"F:\Tara-2017\TARA\Foundation\OpenAPIs\2.json" /namespace:Net.TARA.Foundation /output:"F:\Tara-2017\TARA\Foundation\OpenAPIs\2.cs"
> Output: NSwag command line tool for .NET 4.6.1+ WinX64, toolchain v13.8.2.0 (NJsonSchema v10.2.1.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0))
> Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
> NSwag bin directory: C:\Users\TARA3\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_903d411a\WebTools\Downloads\NSwag.MSBuild\13.8.2\tools\Win
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at NJsonSchema.Infrastructure.JsonSchemaSerialization.FromJson[T](String json, IContractResolver contractResolver)
> at NJsonSchema.Infrastructure.JsonSchemaSerialization.d__13`1.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NSwag.OpenApiDocument.d__57.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NSwag.OpenApiDocument.d__58.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NSwag.Commands.OutputCommandBase.d__9.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NSwag.Commands.InputOutputCommandBase.d__12.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NSwag.Commands.CodeGeneration.SwaggerToCSharpClientCommand.<b__92_0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NSwag.Commands.CodeGeneration.SwaggerToCSharpClientCommand.d__92.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NSwag.Commands.CodeGeneration.SwaggerToCSharpClientCommand.d__91.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.d__12.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.d__11.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.Process(String[] args, Object input)
> at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.Process(String[] args)

I Install-Package NSwag.AspNetCore -Version 13.18.2